# PDF File Preview Not Showing Correctly - Setting "Display alternative file previews" Doesn't Work

Tags: salesforce1-app, pdf, files, servicecloud, preview

I have a problem with PDF File previews which are attached to Account records in Salesforce.

When users enter inside the 'Related' tab and try to preview a PDF file, not all the contents inside the PDF show up. In the screenshot below, the cells appear to have no content, when the data is really there (it appears after downloading and opening the file)

[image: PDF Fiole with missing content]

This issue happens from tablets and the Salesforce mobile app

I tried to fix it by enabling the setting called "Display alternative file previews" (going to Setup > Salesforce Files > General Settings) but it isn't working either, so I'm trying to find another alternative fix.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000382573&type=1

If anyone has a suggestion it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all.